# How to append to an array in a object in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example I have the following Schema:

```
{
    title:String,
    content:String,
    votes:{
        up:[ObjectId],
        down:[ObjectId]
    }
}
```

and I wish to append the up array. How do I use the $addToSet in Mongoose to append it?

I've tried these:

```
Article.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id, 
    {$addToSet:{votes:{up:req.user.id}}}, 
    null,
    function(asdf){
        console.log(asdf);
});
```

This is the error message I get:

```
[MongoError: exception: Cannot apply $addToSet to a non-array field. Field named 'votes' has a non-array type Object in the document _id: ObjectId('55e975801026f4e02a17e77b')]
```

and

```
Article.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id, 
    {$addToSet:{votes.up:req.user.id}}, 
    null,
    function(asdf){
        console.log(asdf);
});
```

And for this one:

```
Article.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$addToSet:{votes.up:ObjectID(req.u
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Comment: You'll only get "that error" from the first statement. The second one will work, unless your underlying data does not match the schema. Well if you "quoted" as in `"votes.up"` then it works. Read["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

Comment: @BlakesSeven I've update the question for the error message I'm getting.

Comment: But did you read the part about "quoting" and apply it? I think you have not done that. Also, there is zero need to "cast" with Mongoose. If the field type in the schema is `ObjectId` then mongoose will do the "casting" for you.

Comment: @BlakesSeven And when I'm using the `"votes.up"` in quotes I get: `[MongoError: exception: '$addToSet' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$addToSet: {<field>: ...}}]`

Comment: Well is not the error obvious? There is no data in the variable you are asking it to submit. Add logging to your code. Clearly `req.user.id` is not defined and should likely be `req.params.id`. This is just an exercise in typing mistakes and basic syntax errors.

Comment: @BlakesSeven It is defined. I just logged it before the execution of this statement. Both `req.user.id` and `req.params.id` are defined.

Comment: Are you reading anything I am saying here? Or just arguing back? I have already pointed out everything that is possibly wrong here. You are simply not following everything you have been told here. 1. "quote" the dot notated field. 2. **Do not cast** 3. check your vars ( maybe req.user is from as session, I don't know as there is no code here to suggest that ) 4. You have the wrong collection or database. 5. present the underlying collection data for the supposed match and true collection name. 6. Show your database connection and shell connection methods to that database. This is not hard.

Comment: I'm sorry. There was a typo that I missed. Sorry once again @BlakesSeven